# How to find the first undefined array element in javascript, to fill it?

Tags: javascript

If entries are being added and removed in an array (not pushed/popped) what is the optimal way to scan and find the first undefined element, so that it can be set with a new value?

Comment: check `undefined` during insert -_- ..then you can live `undefined` free life

Comment: could you show what the array looks like

Comment: Related: how to know if an array has any defined elements in it? (any that are not undefined)

Answer (score 3):

If the array contains holes with `findIndex` you can find the first one like so:

```
[1, 2,, 4, 5].findIndex(Object.is.bind(null, undefined))
```

`indexOf` will ignore holes. So

```
[1, 2,, 4, 5].indexOf(undefined)
```

Always returns `-1`.

Comment: I tested this with an array of length 4, but having only `undefined` values as a content, its not working in this case, using an array created by `new Array(4)` for example. (tested inside an angular 5 demo app)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have no prior knowledge of operations being performed on the array, the fastest way is to simply iterate through the entire array linearly

```
var arr = [1, 2, , 4];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] === 'undefined') {
    arr[i] = 'foo';
    break;
  }
}
```

Or we can keep track of whats being removed using something like this

```
var earliestRemoved;

if (newRemoved < earliestRemoved || !earliestRemoved) {
  earliestRemoved = newRemoved;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way would be to use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of the first `undefined` element.

Comment: `indexOf` ignores holes. So no.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've got the same question, so here's my take on it.

It all depends on your specific problem. My problem was this:

- I have an array `instances[]`, with objects in it;
- Methods of some of these are registered as callbacks elsewhere;
- Sometimes I do need to remove some instance from an array;
- Sometimes I need to add new instance;

The problem is that I can't just splice an array, because it'll invalidate all my callback registrations. Well, I can just leave them in the array and forget, adding new elements at the end. But it's.... bad. It's leaking memory.

So I came with an idea of making "holes" in an array in place of removed elements, and then re-using these holes for new elements.

Thus the question "how to find undefined elements in an array?".

Someone here suggested using `array.indexOf(undefined)` - unfortunately that won't work... for some reason.

But, if it's okay in your case to use `null` or `0` instead, then it *will* work.

Here's an example:

```
var A = [1,1,1,1, , ,0,0,null,1,1];
A.indexOf(undefined);   // output: -1 (doesn't work)
A.indexOf(0);           // output: 6
A.indexOf(null);        // output: 8
```

Hope this'll be useful.

Answer (score 0):

With the hindsight of about 4.3 years behind me, What I'd do now is, since I'm the owner of the array, is to make an object with 2 arrays in it, the 2nd just contains the indexes that are cleared out.  (prob. manage it in a class).  So always have clear set with knowledge of what's undefined.
This to avoid iterating through arrays linearly.

Answer (score 0):

## 2021

Nowadays you can safely use:

```
myArray.findIndex((element) => (typeof element === "undefined"));
```